# Better solution to avoid struggle with the property rename in a class

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I created the following simple class

```
class Animal{
    constructor(feet) {
       this.feet = feet; //I mean paws.I think it should be in the prototype of subclass but here is an example
    }

  set feet(value){
    if(Number.isInteger(value) && value>0) {
       this._feet = value;
    }
    else {
      //Print a message report
      throw new Error('Invalid Initialization');
    }
  }

  get feet(){
    return this._feet;
  }

  static calcFeet(...animals)
  {
    return animals.reduce((prev,cur) => prev+cur.feet , 0);
  }

}

const an1 = new Animal(2);
const an2 = new Animal(4);

console.log(an1.feet); //2
console.log(an2.feet); //4
console.log(Animal.calcFeet(an1,an2)); //6
```

I have setter and getter to check integrity of the value for the property `feet` and an utility method on the constructor Animal. Everything nice but in this way if I would to change the name property `feet` in `paws` I should do it in several points of the code class definition. Thus I implemented an alternative version:

```
class Animal{
    constructor(paws) {
       this.setPaws(paws);
    }

    setPaws(paws){
      if(Number.isInteger(paws) && paws>0) {
        this.paws = paws;
      }
      else {
        //Print a message report
        throw new Error('Invalid Initialization');
      }
    }

  getPaws(){
    return this.paws;
  }

  static calcFeet(...animals)
  {
    return animals.reduce((prev,cur) => prev+cur.getPaws() , 0);
  }

}

const an1 = new Animal(2);
const an2 = new Animal(4);

console.log(an1.getPaws()); //2
console.log(an2.getPaws()); //4
console.log(Animal.calcFeet(an1,an2)); //6
```

I was wondering  if the latest version is more correct than first both from software engineering point of view or from javascript style perspective. And if it isn't the case what could be a cleanest up implementation?

Comment: "if I would to change the name property `feet` in `paws` I should do it in several points of the code class definition." - use an IDE with a "Refactor Rename" capability - or use TypeScript. In fact, everyone should just be using TypeScript at this point.

Comment: You generally shouldn't change names that are part of the external interface to the class. You can add `paws` as a new name, but should leave `feet`. You can then define the setter and getter for one of the names to call the other name.